# Pandas: Converting timeseries of values to tracking changes in value

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I've been stumped on this and - uncharacteristically - the internet has been little help. I am working in Pandas but I feel this must be a general problem for people aiming to store timeseries data efficiently.

I have lots of standard daily time series data where the values happen to change infrequently, like this:

`Date        Value
01/02/2014   .1
01/03/2014   .1
01/04/2014   .5
01/05/2014   .5
01/06/2014   .5
01/07/2014   .1`

I would convert the data to only track days where a value changes, so the above example should now look like this:

`Date        Value
01/02/2014   .1
01/04/2014   .5
01/07/2014   .1`

Unfortunately using something like `drop_duplicates()` would delete required values in a case where a value reverts back to a prior value (like .1 in my example above).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a combination of `shift` and `all`:

```
In [98]:

import io
temp = """Date,Value
01/02/2014,.1
01/03/2014,.1
01/04/2014,.5
01/05/2014,.5
01/06/2014,.5
01/07/2014,.1"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp))
df
Out[98]:
         Date  Value
0  01/02/2014    0.1
1  01/03/2014    0.1
2  01/04/2014    0.5
3  01/05/2014    0.5
4  01/06/2014    0.5
5  01/07/2014    0.1

In [99]:

df.loc[(df.shift() != df).all(axis=1)]
Out[99]:
         Date  Value
0  01/02/2014    0.1
2  01/04/2014    0.5
5  01/07/2014    0.1
```

Here we compare the shifted (by 1 row) dataframe with the original dataframe, we then want to compare each column and use `all` and pass `axis=1` to achieve this.

Further breakdown, if we look at what `df.shift() != df` returns:

```
In [100]:

df.shift() != df
Out[100]:
   Date  Value
0  True   True
1  True  False
2  True   True
3  True  False
4  True  False
5  True   True
```

We get a dataframe with boolean values but we can't use this as a mask as is, we want to check that all rows are `True` so we use `all`:

```
In [101]:

(df.shift() != df).all()
Out[101]:
Date      True
Value    False
dtype: bool
```

However, by default it checks that the columns are all `True`, we want to check the row values so we pass `axis=1`:

```
In [102]:

(df.shift() != df).all(axis=1)
Out[102]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool
```

We can now use this as our boolean mask to achieve what we wanted:

```
In [103]:

df.loc[(df.shift() != df).all(axis=1)]
Out[103]:
         Date  Value
0  01/02/2014    0.1
2  01/04/2014    0.5
5  01/07/2014    0.1
```

Comment: hmm...though we added this to the cookbook (and maybe main docs somewhere). want to do that? a complete example of this

Comment: @Jeff happy to, is it just a link to this answer?

Comment: I think a small complete example would be nice (I find that the inline-code is better for a small example)

Comment: @Jeff do I need to download the source and compile it: http://pandas.pydata.org/developers.html#contributing-to-the-documentation not sure if I will encounter issues as I'm using WinPython which shipped with python

Comment: sorry about being a window user :), pretty non-trival to install; this may help: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/tree/master/scripts/windows_builder; these are some scripts I use to build

Comment: @Jeff thanks for the link, I'll give it a crack and see how I get on, I'd like to contribute more rather than just my basic answers on SO

Comment: just found this nice link: http://cowboyprogrammer.org/building-python-wheels-for-windows/